# Why isn't my Triangle object being drawn?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am creating an OpenGL program which simply creates a triangle and draws it on the screen. I have created a class called Drawable which contains the draw function, as well as the VAO & VBO objects which are used. I have also created a Triangle class which inherits from the Drawable class. In the Triangle class I have a constructor which takes an array of points and a single array containing a color, and it initializes the VAO & VBO (which are inherited from Drawable) using this data.

In my main function I initialize the Triangle using point and color data and then call the draw function on the Triangle object (this draw function is in Drawable).  Ultimately though, the window opens and the triangle is not drawn. I have a simple constructor in the Drawable class, and if I initialize the object using this constructor and call the draw function it will display the object so I don't think its my draw function. The only thing I could think of is that because of how I am accessing the VAO & VBO objects maybe they aren't actually getting initialized to anything, but I don't know how to check that.

Drawable.h

```
class Drawable
{
    public:
        Drawable();

        void draw();
        GLuint objBuffer, VAO, program;
        std::string vShaderName, fShaderName;
        bool isUniform = false;
        int numVertices = 0;
        vec4 uniformColorVec;
};
```

Drawable.cpp

```
Drawable::Drawable()
{}

void Drawable::draw()
{
        GLuint program = InitShader(vShaderName.c_str(), fShaderName.c_str());
        glUseProgram(program);
        GLuint color_loc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "color");

        glBindVertexArray(VAO);

        glUniform4fv(color_loc, 1, uniformColorVec);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, numVertices);

}
```

Triangle.cpp

```
Triangle::Triangle(vec4 triPoints[3], vec4 color)
{
    uniformColorVec = color;

    vShaderName = "vshader00_v150.glsl";
    fShaderName = "fshader00_v150.glsl";
    numVertices = 3;

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &objBuffer);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, objBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(triPoints), triPoints, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    program = InitShader(vShaderName.c_str(), fShaderName.c_str());
    glUseProgram(program);

    GLuint vPosition = glGetAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
    GLuint color_loc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "color");

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

    glUniform4fv(color_loc, 1, uniformColorVec);

}
```

main file

```
/* All the OpenGL windowing is intialized but I won't 
    include that since I know it's fine due to other objects being drawn
    correctly */


vec4 triPoints2[3] = {
    vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0),
    vec4(-0.75, -0.75, 1.0, 1.0),
    vec4(0.0, -0.75, 1.0, 1.0)
};

vec4 blue_opaque = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);

Triangle t;
t = Triangle(triPoints2, blue_opaque);

glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);

t.draw();

glFlush();
```

Comment: What `glGetError` says? Also I advise against using `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`, because it's history.

Comment: @ybungalobill `glGetError` is showing a 0, so it is not reporting any errors.

Comment: What happens if you change the `Triangle t; t = Triangle(triPoints2, blue_opaque);` lines to `Triangle t(triPoints2, blue_opaque);`?

Comment: Seems to be the same thing. Just an empty white window. I have some `cout`'s in there and it shows the correct number of vertices getting passed to the Triangle constructor and the Drawable display function too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function gets a `vec4 triPoints[3]` argument, but by C++ rules it's equivalent to `vec4 *triPoints` as a function argument. As a result `sizeof(triPoints)` is not the size of the data but rather the size of the pointer itself (either 4 or 8). Instead, change it to:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(*triPoints)*numVertices, triPoints, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate your help.